# What is Reddit API address to call front page?

Tags: api, reddit

I would like to use the Reddit API to get info about the front page, but even after reading through the docs I can't find it.

I tried using:

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/all/hot/.json
http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json
```

But neither of these match the front page. Is the front page as presented not available?

p.s. also it's not because I am logged in when browsing because I am not logged int.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you're getting the JSON representation of /r/all; if you want to look at the homepage (https://www.reddit.com/), request https://www.reddit.com/.json .